# Printing barcode from Live server is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

> We are developing a website using ASP.net where on button click user can print the barcode of particular product. We are using TSC label printer. The code prints barcode on local server but it doesn't work on live server.

> So is there any way to print barcode on client machine.

Comment: what code you have written for this? Can you share the code? There are possibilities that the client machine does not have the specific printer or it has more than one different printers attached to it.

Comment: You asked this (bad) question already and it got closed because nobody can answer this as is...

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean this does not work? If you plug that printer into the live server, and setup the printer on the live server, then that printer will work just like it does on your current computer you been testing on.

So, you have this:

[image]

so, in that server room, ONE of those racks has your web site, and you have to plug in the printer into that server JUST like you did during testing.

So, to quote you:

> The code prints barcode on local server but it doesn't work on live server

If the bar code printer works on that local server, then it should work on the production server. in both cases, you of course did setup the printer for that given server, correct?

The above picture shows how this will work for the production server. You have to just ensure the "one" server in the server room has that printer plugged into the production server, and this should work.

So that should work just fine. Of course this type of printing has little to do with a browser that can't really control a printer, but that was not your question.

so, when the bar code is printed, you have to go down to the server room, and that server that has the printer attached to will have printed for you.